Please help identify old animated film, maybe anime film
Please, I need help to identify an old animated film I saw when I was a really young child, that might be an old Japanese animated film (anime). 
I was born in 1982, and I do not recall the exact year when I saw it, but I am convinced it happened in the 80's, and I saw it on TV. This is what I can remember from it:

The main characters were a group of people between 4 and 6 I think, male and female.
They were in what appeared to be outer space
They arrived in what I think was some kind of planet, with some kind of closed structure similar to a maze, with lots of corridors
They were searching for something of value inside this structure
They were chased by some kind of sphere, I think it was white. I think they couldn't escape from this place, and I think I remember some booby traps also
In contact with this sphere, the character dies
They all get killed by the end of the movie, by this sphere

This is all I can remember from it. I've been trying to find this movie my whole life, but I was so young when I saw it, and remember so little of it. Please, somebody out there must have seen this film too.

God, this sounds so much like Heavy Metal, but can't be, because that sphere I believe was green, and there weren't children in it.

Possibly Heavy Metal.
The sphere you're describing sounds a lot like Loc-Nar, though there are some discrepancies, as August Canaille pointed out, it's green.
http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Loc-Nar

Might be "Les Maîtres du temps".
It does not totally fit but there's an important white sphere and the group contains a child.
